# UITextField override shouldChangeCharactersInRange

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, overriding

I wrote my own subclass of UITextField:

**BWPicker.h**

```
@interface BWPicker : UITextField

    ...

@end
```

**BWPicker.m**

```
@implementation BWPicker

    - (BOOL)shouldChangeTextInRange:(UITextRange *)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
    {
        return NO;
    }

    ...

@end
```

But for some reason, the override does not work, I am still able to edit the content of the textfield.

Another option would be to implement the UITextInputDelegate, but I really do not want to set `self.delegate = self;`.

Are there other ways to prevent editing, preferable without the use of a delegate? (I still want to be able to set the text via `self.text = ...`)

Comment: The correct delegate method name is textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shouldChangeTextInRange` is not a method of `UITextField`, and that explains the reason why override did not work when you subclass `UITextField`, since there was nothing to override.

If you do not want to do self.delegate = self, you can always subclass `UITextFieldDelegate` and implement `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` there, say MyTextFieldDelegate, and set self.delegate to an instance of that. Or simply disable it:

```
someTextField.enabled = NO;
```